# How to select and hide all but first 5 elements in a HTML file (DOM)

Tags: jquery, html, dom, hide, coffeescript

I am attempting to use coffeescript/jQuery to do the following:

1) Retrieve all the 'topics' displayed in the html (seen below)

2) Hide all the topics from display except for the first 5 listed.

[image]

I tried to do the following but is not working

```
//Retrieve the entire list of and hide all but the first 5 topics in the list
$(".topics .topic")[5..-1].hide()
```

Can someone advise me on how I can correctly retrieve the list of topics from the HTML document and subsequently hide ALL but the first 5 topics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(".topics .topic").slice(5).hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Right idea, except the OP wants to hide all except the first 5, not hide the first 5.

Comment: This can't be the solution to the OP's problem, because the CoffeeScript code `$(".topics .topic")[5..-1].hide()` compiles to exactly this. ([Try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24(%22.topics%20.topic%22)%5B5..-1%5D.hide()).)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [jQuery gt() selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$(".topics .topic:gt(4)").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code

```
$(".topics .topic")[5..-1].hide()
```

should work, since it compiles to `$(".topics .topic").slice(5).hide()` and [jQuery's slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) does exactly what you want. So I'm guessing that your code  is running before the DOM is in the right state. Have you tried

```
$(document).ready -> $(".topics .topic")[5..-1].hide()
```

? What do you get when you do

```
alert $(".topics .topic").length
```

at the same point in your script?

If the problem isn't with the selection, then the problem must be with `hide()`, which works by modifying the targets' inline CSS. You may be overriding that CSS elsewhere in your code. Use "Inspect Element" to get details.